# Two custom cells in UICollectionView but second cell is sized incorrectly

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to iOS development and am trying to create a PokeDex app. My main view controller has a collection view which returns two types of custom cells. My first cell called the chooser cell is immediately underneath the navigation bar or header bar whichever term, and I want my second custom cell(descriptioncell) to be immediately underneath the choosercell and take up the entire screen. I originally set the height of the description cell to be the height of the view - 50 to take the chooser cell into account but I saw that there was some space left over which shows the color of the collectionview. I then decided to make the descriptionview the height of the entire view.frame but there is still empty space for some reason. It is not a lot of space and by making the collectionview the same color as my descriptioncell everything would look fine, but why is this happening?

code in viewcontroller:

```
import UIKit

class PokeDexController: UICollectionViewController,      UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

private let cellID = "cellID"
private let cellID2 = "cellID2"


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "PokeDex 386"
    //collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 52/255.0, green: 55/255.0, blue: 64/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    collectionView?.register(chooserCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellID)
    collectionView?.register(DescriptionCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellID2)

}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! chooserCell
        return cell
    }
    else
    {
        let cell2 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellID2, for: indexPath) as! DescriptionCell
        return cell2
    }
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 50)

    }
    else
    {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
    }
}
```

}

[how the app currently looks, empty space between two cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEBir.jpg)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would double check `view.frame` to make sure it is what you expect it to be, just to rule out something simple. More times that I'd like to admit i've used references to another view who's frame was not what I thought it was going to be.

Another thing to check would be the content insets/spacing of the `UICollectionView` especially if you're using storyboards, I don't know if storyboards set a default inset/cell spacing or not. If you *always* seem to have some spacing around the edges of your cells its most likely some padding/spacing configured on the `UICollectionView` itself.

Also a likely culprit can be AutoLayout constraints, by default storyboards attach to layout *margins* not the layout edges. The margins are inset slightly from the true edge creating a gap.

Hopefully that helps some or at least gets you looking in the right places